# passing function results in class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

in my main, all the `print()` works except the last one !! 
if we run this code at the end it will repeat again and start to get my input's.
and if you know any other ways to pass these function result to another one please help me.

### I think it's not very clear.

```
class Student:
    def getMarks(self):
        number_of_students = int(input("please enter the number of students : "))
        students = []
        while number_of_students != 0:
            name = input("please enter the name :")
            mark = input("please enter the mark :")
            x = [name,mark]
            students.append(x)
            number_of_students -= 1
        return students

    def getDict(self):
        dict = {}
        for item in Student.getMarks(self):
            dict[item[0]] = item[1]
        return dict

    def dictItems(self):
        return Student.getDict(self).items()

    def sortMarks(self):
        marks = [x for x in Student.getDict(self).values()]
        return sorted(marks)

    def getIntendMark(self):
        place = 0
        n = 1
        sort = Student.sortMarks(self)
        for item in sort:
            if sort[0] == sort[n]:
                n += 1
            else:
                place = n

        mark = sort[place]
        return mark

    def showAnswer(self):
        nomre = Student.getIntendMark(self)
        dict = Student.dictItems(self)

        for key,value in dict:
            if value == nomre:
                return f"answer:: name is {key} , mark is {nomre}"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Student()
    # print(s.getMarks())
    # print(s.getDict())
    # print(s.sortMarks())
    # print(s.getIntendMark())
    print(s.showAnswer())
```

Comment: This isn't how you write class code in Python. In particular, all those `Student.methodName(self)` calls should be just `self.methodName()`. But also you should be assigning things like the marks as instance attributes.

Comment: i change all those methodNames but still i have problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Student:
    def getMarks(self):
        number_of_students = int(input("please enter the number of students : "))
        students = []
        while number_of_students!=0:
            name = input("please enter the name :")
            mark = input("please enter the mark :")
            x = [name,mark]
            students.append(x)
            number_of_students -= 1
        return students

    def getDict(self):
        dict = {}
        for item in self.getMarks():
            dict[item[0]] = item[1]
        return dict

    def getIntendMark(self):
    dict = self.getDict()
    place = 0
    n = 0 # if you had 1 student it was giving out of bound error
    sort = sorted([x for x in dict.values()])
    if len(sort)>1:  # I check the list length 
        n=1
    print(len(sort))
    for item in sort:
        if sort[0] == sort[n]:
            if n < len(sort):
                n += 1
        else:
            place = n

    mark = sort[place]
    return (mark, dict.items())

    def showAnswer(self):
        nomre,dict = self.getIntendMark()
        #dict = self.getDict().items() #you are calling getMarks() 2nd times

        for key,value in dict:
            if value == nomre:
                return f"answer:: name is {key} , mark is {nomre}"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Student()
    # print(s.getMarks())
    # print(s.getDict())
    # print(s.sortMarks())
    # print(s.getIntendMark())
    print(s.showAnswer())
```

I have made several changes to your code and removed unnecessary methods.

**Output:**

```
(python37) C:\Users\Documents>py test.py
please enter the number of students : 1
please enter the name :e
please enter the mark :2
answer:: name is e , mark is 2
```

Comment: Glad for you! I have spend quite a time to fix it)

Comment: If it solved your question please consider of accepting it so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You call `Student.dictItems` in `showAnswer()`.
In `dictItems` you call `getDict`.
In `getDict` you iterate over `Student.getMarks`, which puts you to the beginning.

I would have posted a solved code, but the whole architecture is not the way how Python considers object orientation to be.

Please read this [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp) through! It will help you in properly designing Python classes.

The `self` is, as the name indicates, a special variable just for **one** instance of a student. You must create an `__init__(self)` function.

Comment: how i have to use __init__ for this

Comment: You would do something like that: 
```class Student:  
def __init__(self):  
    pass # means: do nothing here. You could also add variables like self.name etc.  
def getMarks(self): ...```

You can then create a single student like this:  
```student1 = Student()
student1.getMarks()```  
and `self` will then always be the student you call a method on. In this example `student1`. But it could also be `student28`, if you were creating and using `student28`. You can create multiple students. `self` automatically adjusts. Please read through the article and mark my answer as...

Answer (score 0):

So you have 2 problems:

1. `Return` in a function exits the function. So putting a return in a `for` loop will not work, as it will only run once and then quit the function( and for loop).
2. You call `getMarks()` twice once by:

> getIntendMark() -> sortMarks() -> getDict() -> getMarks()

and the other time by:

> dictItems() -> getDict() -> getMarks()

To fix your code you will need to make some serious adjustments. A good place to start is probably [Object-Oriented Programming in Python](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) in order to get more familiar with what you are actually coding.

Comment: @mujad I added a link to a tutorial that should give you the fundamentals to fix your code.